# Have an age cut-off for very old low-quality response notifications in the delete queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I just got a comment on an answer I posted to a question where I was asking for clarification of the asker's situation, which just said:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

This is a fair comment, but the answer was from late 2008 and I don't recall whether comments even existed at that point. Regardless, I don't have any convenient way of contacting my past self to inform them of this infraction and if I did have one, I would probably use it for lottery numbers.

I can understand why this template exists for recent answers in the delete queue, but once they are a few years old, one might anticipate that either the user has got into the flow of the community or left by now. The answers will need deleting, but perhaps it should be possible to bypass the comments in this kind of case?

Another approach, if these are being fished out automatically, might be to flag up to the original poster "these old answers of yours look like they might not be great, do you want to go back and check?" That might lift a little weight off the delete queue.

I guess there may not be enough old VLQ answers around to justify it, but it felt like I was being told off for not having done something seven years ago that may not have been possible at the time.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see anything wrong or rude about that auto-comment. It's just an informative comment letting you know

- that your old answer doesn't provide an actual answer to the question
- to leave your answer as a comment on the question if you still are looking for clarification from the questioner

There are many things on SO that are new now, that didn't exist way back when. For example, questions with 100's of upvotes may be closed for close reasons that didn't exist until years after the question was asked.

If I had an answer that old and it was NAA, I would want to receive the comment so I would be notified of this fact. Thus I would be able to have the chance to re-review the question/answers and see if there was any other action I'd like to take, like leaving an actual answer now.

> Another approach, if these are being fished out automatically, might be to flag up to the original poster "these old answers of yours look like they might not be great, do you want to go back and check?" That might lift a little weight off the delete queue.

Old answers aren't fished out automatically. Only new ones are. All the old ones that enter the Low Quality Posts queue were flagged by a user. That queue has been receiving a lot more posts to review since they added an hour delay before they get sent to a moderator to review, if sent to them at all. However, that queue still is being handled pretty well, so don't think we need to do anything as of now to lessen the weight off that queue.

If a user is interested in improving old answers of theirs that likely need improvement, they can go back and review their answers manually (*I know not practical for users with thousands of answers*), or write/use a SEDE query to help find answers that may be of lower quality.

Comment: I'm curious how veterans of the site feel about getting at least one or two of these comments on their old posts every single day for months on end.

Comment: "every single day" might have been an exaggeration. Perhaps it's more like once or twice a week. But you get my drift. Your suggestion means every answer will still potentially receive at least one comment - but there's no other way to notify a user whenever one of their answers is fished out. There has to be another way to do this without pissing people off...